# Up-sampling images and the Periodicity of the copies

Tags: frequency-spectrum, upsampling

In the three figures below, $H(e^{j\omega})$, $H(e^{2j\omega})$, and $H(e^{4j\omega})$ are shown. I understand that up-sampling shrinks the spectrum. However, I need a few clarifications:

1. Why does up-sampling result in the creation of new copies (imaging)?
2. What is the periodicity of the images? In other words, how, for example, in the third figure, the second spectrum is located at $\pi/2$ and the third spectrum is centered at $\pi$?

For the second question, I think $H(e^{j\omega})$ has a $2\pi$ periodicity, and as a result, $H(e^{2j\omega})$ becomes $\pi$ periodic, and so on. If that's the case, then why doesn't the second spectrum start at $\pi$, but instead, it is centered at $\pi$?

Thanks
[image: Upsampled Spectrum]

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the [wikipedia article on upsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling). If you still need clarification, feel free to come back, but it should answer your question (pay particular attention to the *interpolation filter design* section).

Comment: Thanks, I read the article. I believe the images are drawn incorrectly. They should not be centered but should start at those frequencies.

Comment: I've written a short answer explaining where I think your confusion comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are drawn correctly, albeit slightly confusingly.

I think your confusion comes from the fact that the $\pi$ in the 1st picture **isn't the same as the $\pi$ in the 2nd or 3rd**.  For all 3, $\pi$ is the normalized Nyquist frequency ($f_s/2$ where $f_s$ is the sampling rate) **associated with the corresponding picture**.

As you're aware, after discretization at sampling rate $f_s$, the spectrum becomes periodic with centers at $...,-4\pi, -2\pi, 0, 2\pi, 4\pi ...$, which is equivalent to $..., -4f_s, -2f_s, 0, f_s, 2f_s, ...$

In the first picture, the image centered at $2\pi$ is not represented, but it is there.
Let's call $f_{s1}$ the first sampling frequency.  When you upsample by $2$, you get a new Nyquist frequency $f_{s2} = 2f_{s1}$. The image that was centered at $f_{s1}$ hasn't moved, but in terms of $f_{s2}$ it is now at $f_{s2}/2$. In terms of normalized frequency **for $f_{s2}$**, that's $\pi$.

Same principle applies for the 3rd picture. Hope that helped.